# ASP.NET MVC 2: Connection String error?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, web-config, connection-string

I needed to start fresh with a new MVC 2 Project

This is what the error points to:

```
public DealDataContext() : 
                    base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RESTRO_DEVConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
            {
                OnCreated();
            }
```

The only difference between the two projects could possibly that the first one was not an EMPTY MVC 2 Project... whereas the second one was.

Are there some definitions or settings that differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is looking for a connection string in a web.config file**. The connection string is named "RESTRO_DEVConnectionString" in that web.config file.

If you don't have this in your new web.config file, you can probably copy the line of XML fro the original web.config file.

Comment: with a multi-project solution, does the connection string reference need to be in each project web.config file?

Comment: Solution projects which are web applications have web.config files which should contain their connection strings. Other solution projects can have app.config files but should rely on the application's web.config to tell them which database to use.